# How to get price total of dynamically created rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I want to SUM the price of all dynamically created rows and display into total input field..I have tried some things but not working for me.I have posted my script and image that explains how it should works. Everything is working and saving in database just want total amount of all items. Please see image for clear concept. Total of 1st row is saving in total but not working for dynamically created rows.

Image:
 [It should work like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkOED.jpg)

Html:

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Total</label>
      <input readonly type="text" id="total_amount" class="form-control"
       name="total_amount">
    </div>
```

Script:

```
 <script>
    var counterr = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#unit_price,#item_quantity').change(function () {
            // alert();
            var unitPrice = $('#unit_price').val();
            // console.log(unitPrice);
            var quantity = $('#item_quantity').val();
            // console.log(quantity);

            var total = (unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(0);

            $('#total_price').val(total);
            $('#total_amount').val(total);

        });


        // Input Fields


        var maxField = 100; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('#add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper

        $(addButton).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counterr++;
            //Check maximum number of input fields
            if (counterr < maxField) {
                fieldHTML = makeNewRow(counterr);
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
                // $('#department-'+counterr).select2();

                // console.log("Unit price", counterr);
                $('.unit_price' + counterr).change(function () {
                    // console.log("hello");
                    var unitPrice = $('.unit_price' + counterr).val();
                    // console.log(unitPrice);
                    var quantity = $('#item_quantity' + counterr).val();
                    // console.log(quantity);

                    var total = (unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(0);

                    $('#total_price' + counterr).val(total);


                     $('#total_price').each(function() {
                    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
                    console.log('test',subtotal);
                });
                 $('#total_amount').val(subtotal);

                });


            }

        });


        //Once remove button is clicked
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('#newrow').remove(); //Remove field html
            counterr = counterr--; //Decrement field counter
        })


    });

    function makeNewRow(counterr) {

        return '<div class="row" id="newrow">' +
            '<div class="col-md-4">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<select onChange="getPurchasePrice(this.value);" style="background-color: #f5f6f9" id="item_name' + counterr + '" class="form-control dep"' +
            'placeholder="Enter Item" name="testing[]"' + '>' +
            '<option value = "">Select Item</option>' + '>' +
            '@foreach($items as $item)' + '>' +
            '<option value = "{{$item->id}}">{{$item->item_name}}</option>' + '>' +
            '@endforeach' + '>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<input style="background-color: #f5f6f9" type="number" id="item_quantity' + counterr + '" class="form-control"' +
            'placeholder="Enter.." name="testing[]"' + '>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<input style="background-color: #f5f6f9" type="number" id="unit_price' + counterr + '" class="unit_price' + counterr + ' form-control"' +
            'placeholder="Enter.." name="testing[]"' + '>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-3">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<input value="0" style="background-color: #f5f6f9" disabled type="text" id="total_price' + counterr + '" class="form-control"' +
            'placeholder="Total" name="testing[]"' + '>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<a style="height:40px;margin-left:25px" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger remove_button">X</a>' +
            '</div>'; //New input field html
    }

    /*function removeDiv(no){
        $("#testingrow-"+no).remove();
        x--;
    }*/


</script>
```

Comment: please create a working copy and tried to run but nothing worked

Comment: You use 'total_price' control name inside your script instead of 'total_amount' html control.

Comment: @mgsdew total_price is the total of  item where total_amount is the sum of all items total.

Comment: @brk the total of 1st item is saving in total but  not working for dynamically created rows.

Comment: Then declare a global variable named as like 'subTotal'. Assign your total value inside there likes, 
subTotal += total; 
and at the end of your function assign sub-total value likes,  
$('#total_price').val(subTotal);

Comment: @mgsdew I have updated my code please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function to recalculate the grand total 'recalcGrandTotal'

```
var recalcGrandTotal = function() {
    var grandTotal = 0; // Declare a var to hold the grand total
    $("[id^=total_price]").each(function() { // Find all elements with an id that starts with 'total_price'
        grandTotal += parseInt($(this).val()); // Add the value of the 'total_price*' field to the grand total
      })
  $('#total_amount').val(grandTotal); // append grand total amount to the total field
}
```

Then, hook this function up to the 'total price' recalculation function: 
Find

```
$('#total_price' + counterr).val(total);
```

Add after:

```
recalcGrandTotal();
```

To substract from grand total upon removal of an item, hook this function up to the item removal function. Find:

```
counterr = counterr--; //Decrement field counter
```

Add after:

```
recalcGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Hook up this function to the removal function as well. Find: _counterr = counterr--;_ add after: _recalcGrandTotal();_

Comment: I'm facing one issue when i create 3 rows then i when i change the quantity and unit price of 2nd row then total price not changed... If you can fix this issue please do.. otherwise its okay. Working when i edit 1st and last row..

Comment: @DaniyalMughal I believe that is due to duplicate ID's, you should replace them with classes.